# Two plugins in a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to use two plug-ins in one element on my page. I've never needed to do this and tried as it is in the code below. Most did not work!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    var wbbOpt = {buttons: "bold,italic,underline,|,img,link,|,code,quote"}

    // plugin one wysibb
    $("#editor").wysibb(wbbOpt);
    // plugin two hashtags
    $("#editor").hashtags();
    //the two plugin worked in textarea #editor
});
</script>
```

Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Comment: Could you show the code of 'hashtags()' in order to know what is happening? I supposed that 'wyssib()' is the WYSIWYG BBCode editor based on jQuery, but no idea of 'hashtags()'

Comment: You could isolate the problem by telling what you want to do first. Most plugins, after acting on an element, might not leave it the way another plugin would need it.

Comment: The codes are great for me to post here ... http://www.wysibb.com/docs/ and http://doenervich.github.io/jquery-hashtags/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can't use them because each of them take control and wrap the textarea. Since the editor is the most complex of the two the best thing to do is to take the code of the hashtag and adapt it at your need.

So here's a working example, but if you want you can trigger the function I use to the change event (adding it) or some way else

```
<div id="higlighter" style="width;1217px;"></div>
<textarea id="editor"></textarea>
<br />
<input id="btn" type="button" value="HASH">
<br />

$(document).ready(function() {
var wbbOpt = {
buttons: "bold,italic,underline,|,img,link,|,code,quote"
};


$("#editor").wysibb(wbbOpt);    

$('#btn').click(function () { report() });

});


function report() {

    $("#hashtag").val($("#editor").htmlcode());

            var str = $("#editor").htmlcode();
            str = str.replace(/\n/g, '<br>');
            if(!str.match(/(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;\/~+#-])?#([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/g)) {
                if(!str.match(/#([a-zA-Z0-9]+)#/g)) {
                    str = str.replace(/#([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/g,'<span class="hashtag2">#$1</span>');
                }else{
                    str = str.replace(/#([a-zA-Z0-9]+)#([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/g,'<span class="hashtag2">#$1</span>');
                }
            }
            $("#editor").htmlcode(str);

}
```

you can check a working code here on jsfiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/4kj7d6mh/2/

You can type your text and use the editor, and when you want to higlight the hastag you click the button. If you want that to happen automatically you have to change this line:

```
 $('#btn').click(function () { report() });
```

And attach the function to the keypress for example (experiment a bit)